# How to split a tsv file in bash with keys and values?

Tags: bash, csv

I have a tsv file like this:

```
nconst  primaryName birthYear   deathYear   primaryProfession   knownForTitles
nm0000001   Fred Astaire    1899    1987    soundtrack,actor,miscellaneous  tt0053137,tt0043044,tt0050419,tt0072308
nm0000002   Lauren Bacall   1924    2014    actress,soundtrack  tt0117057,tt0038355,tt0037382,tt0071877
nm0000003   Brigitte Bardot 1934    \N  actress,soundtrack,producer tt0059956,tt0057345,tt0049189,tt0054452
nm0000004   John Belushi    1949    1982    actor,soundtrack,writer tt0077975,tt0078723,tt0080455,tt0072562
nm0000005   Ingmar Bergman  1918    2007    writer,director,actor   tt0069467,tt0050986,tt0050976,tt0083922
```

I want to extract the `primaryName` and `knownForTitles` columns of each row and print it out. I don't know how to do this in bash scripting language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This awk one-liner should help:

```
awk -F'\t' '{print $2, $NF}' file.tsv
```

Comment: thank you for your response. Just one question, what if I wanted to store these tow columns into two vriables?

Comment: what do you want to do with the two vars afterwards? if it can be done in awk, you can assign awk variables. otherwise, you can create a bash loop to handle the variables. @Mohammadreza

Comment: I want to sue the in condition vriables